# How to get video thumbnails?

Tags: java, android, video, thumbnails

I have created a media player and it is working. The issue I have is that only the video names are displayed in my list view. How can I see the name and a thumbnail image of the video in my list view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Video Thumbnails in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179/video-thumbnails-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across [this SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179/video-thumbnails-in-java) while searching to answer your question. Not sure if that will work on Android or not. You give it a try.