# Is there any api to create thumbnil of my video that is presen in my own server not in other?

Tags: java, image, struts2, video-processing

I am going to create a application where i need to show the thumbnil image of those video that is present in the server.Some site like youtube they have an link if we put it in  tag it will show that video thumbnil.I just want to know is there any api to do so for my video?

Comment: you can read the accepted answer of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179/video-thumbnails-in-java) post. please also read the last answer on the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use mplayer and Runtime.exec()