# How to create thumbnail of a video?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, video, thumbnails

I have a jsp page for users to upload video.
I am able to store uploaded video as blob in datastore 
but I want to create thumbnail from the uploaded video as well. 
How do I create the thumbnail?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179/video-thumbnails-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending of classes which you use to operate over MIME objects in Java, you should be able to obtain random frame from the video (let's say as **BufferedImage**) and then resize it to desired thumbnail size.