# How to create video thumbnail from video file path in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, video-thumbnails

I want to create thumbnail of video from sdcard path how can i generate thumbnail from video file path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Video Thumbnails in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179/video-thumbnails-in-java)

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha The duplicate doesn't have any javaFX answers.  Still the best is probably the ffmpeg solution.